# MySQL Select from 2 unrelated tables and insert values into a third

Tags: mysql-error-1064

I would like to create a selection and insert query that would select from `Customers` table `name` and `customer_number` and from the `Stock` table select `inven_code` and `quant_left`.

The third table is named `sales` and there is nothing in it yet. I want to insert the results of the above select query in the sales table.

Here is what the tables structure looks like:

**customers** table:

```
Name VARCHAR (50)  customer_number CHAR (7) PRIMARY KEY
Jack Rafuse        CUST123
Susan Jackson      CUST456
```

**stock** table:

```
product_name VARCHAR(50)  inven_code CHAR (6) PRIMARY KEY   quant_left INT
baseballs                 123456                                6
bats                      789101                                3
```

**sales** table:

```
Id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT
customer_number VARCHAR(50) 
Inven_code CHAR (6) 
quant_left INT
```

Heres the query with the selection code that I have but it is giving an error:

```
$query = "INSERT INTO sales (customer_number, inven_code, quant_left)

          SELECT customers.customer_number, stock.inven_code, stock.quant_left 
          FROM customers, stock     
          WHERE Customers.customer_number='CUST123' AND
                Stock.inven.code='123456' AND
                Stock.quant_left ='6' “;

$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error($link));
```

This is the error that I am getting:

*You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT customers.customer_number,stock.inven_code,stock.quant_left at line 2*

Any assistance that can be offered is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

if we assume your select query works which you can test it separately in mysql console environment. try the following:

```
insert into sales  select 0, customers.customer_number, stock.inven_code, stock.quant_left from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not in your query properly said, but in your PHP code as your closing quotes are not the right ones.

Replace `“` by `"` as follows:

```
<?php
$query = "INSERT INTO sales (customer_number, inven_code, quant_left)    
          SELECT C.customer_number, S.inven_code, S.quant_left 
          FROM customers C, stock S   
          WHERE C.customer_number='CUST123' AND
                S.inven.code='123456' AND
                S.quant_left ='6'";

$result = mysql_query($query, $link) or die(mysql_error($link));
?>
```

This that I just aliased your tables' names so that the code can be lighter. Also, this is just a way to make your code run, otherwise you must know that mysql_* is deprecated. You need to use [mysqli_*](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [PDO](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.pdo.php) instead along with [prepared statements](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) in order to avoid [SQL injections](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection).